# Static image in Shiny app not found (HTTP status 404)

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to put a static image into a Shiny app. I have created a folder called `www` in the working directory of my Shiny app and put a PNG file there. Using the following code should show the image:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$img(src='photo.png')
)
  
server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

But instead I have this:

[image]

Querying the image URL (`http://127.0.0.1:7122/photo.png`) directly shows a 404 status code.

The outcome is the same regardless of whether I start the Shiny app by running the code manually, clicking the "Run App" button in RStudio, or executing the file via `Rscript app.R` on the command line.

Here is the folder structure:

```
.
├── app.R
└── www
    └── photo.png
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: I tested your code and it worked fine. The only thing I can think of is maybe your photo isn't named photo? src='photo.png' means that your file is called "photo.png". If that is the case then sorry otherwise replace "photo" with your file name. That's the only problem I can think of assuming the www folder is in your app folder (as mentioned in the answer below).

Comment: @EliBerkow I've taken the liberty of adding some more details to this (old) question. The code definitely doesn't work for me; not on Windows, nor on Linux. This is true across different versions of R and Shiny. The app otherwise works, but static resources don't get served under `/`. By contrast, adding a new resource prefix via `addResourcePath` works.

Comment: That is very strange. I tried again and it works fine for me. I'm assuming running in the browser gives the same outcome?

Comment: "Works for me" if I do as you hint above and a) add a resource path and b) update the image source URL to use the resource path.  And it strikes as that may even be the intent to, say, not inadvertently disclose server resources?

Comment: @Dirk According to the documentation, (only) the `www` subfolder servers resources by default. That seems safe to me.

Comment: Do the docs say what lead prefix it gets (in the `addResourcePath("img", "www")` sense)?  When I "demonstrated" this to myself, the `print(resourcePath())` showed only directories 'internal' to the package (and from the package's own installation directory) -- apart from the one I very explicitly added and which then worked in `tags$img(src='/img/photo.png')`.

Comment: @Dirk According to [the documentation](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.4.0/resourcePaths.html), it gets the prefix `/`.

Comment: So maybe we have a case of documentation and behaviour being out of whack?

Comment: I’ve [reported a bug](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/3742).

Answer (score 5):

I don't think this is a bug - there is some documentation missing.

The issue here is, that the default resource publishing via the `www` folder using the `/` prefix is implemented only for [two-file](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/two-file.html) (server.R and ui.R) and [single-file](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/app-formats.html) (app.R) shiny apps - *not for shiny app objects* (the object returned by `shinyApp()`). This makes sense, as in contrast to e.g. the app.R file a shiny app object doesn't reside in a fixed directory.

The `www` folder to `/` prefix mapping only takes place if `runApp`'s `appDir` parameter is provided with a directory or file path (string object). The character method can be seen [here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/blob/ed6022e3f2ea2a0c7dd8333af1e2466f0aeffcc5/R/shinyapp.R#L536). Another relevant function (downstream) can be found [here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/blob/ed6022e3f2ea2a0c7dd8333af1e2466f0aeffcc5/R/shinyapp.R#L189).

Once a shiny app object is passed to runApp's `appDir` argument we need to use `addResourcePath`, which is the case when running `runApp(shinyApp(ui, server))`.

Accordingly the following works:

```
library(shiny)

addResourcePath("prefix", "www")

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$img(src='prefix/photo.png')
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

appObj <- shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)

runApp(appObj)
# print(appObj) # also works
```

Comment: If nothing else *it's a bug in the documentation*. Furthermore, you *cannot* use `addResourcePath` with the prefix `/`, so there seemingly is no way to make this work with an app object. What this answer is missing (for me) is a workaround/fix to make the original code work.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I definitely agree - the documentation regarding resource publishing via the `www` directory is poor. Without modifying shiny I don't think there is a way to make the original code work (as a shiny object) because as you already mentioned slashes are not allowed in the prefix using `addResourcePath` - for future readers please check `?addResourcePath`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph the only thing you could do (if you want to avoid using `addResourcePath`) is copying your resources to shiny's `fallbackWWWDir` located here: `system.file("www-dir", package = "shiny")`. Please see this [line](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/blob/ed6022e3f2ea2a0c7dd8333af1e2466f0aeffcc5/R/shinyapp.R#L196).

Comment: That location will not generally be user-writeable, nor *should* it be modified (it's part of the package installation, after all!). Luckily in my particular case I can just use `runApp('.')` instead. But in general I think `shinyApp` needs to gain an argument to specify the `www` path. In the meantime, a generally usable workaround requires generating the necessary Shiny file/folder structure on the fly (i.e. create an `app.r` file adjacent to the `www` dir, write the Shiny app into it, and then run `shinyApp('app.r')`.

Comment: Yes - a proper built-in solution should be the way to go - My answer is just reflecting the status quo. Let's see what the shiny team responds on GitHub.

Comment: The RStudio Community discussion actually contains an interesting approach to solving this in code. Since it uses Shiny internals it should not be relied on in the future, but it's a viable workaround for now (I added this workaround to my answer).

Comment: You are right - so far I never had the need to stick with the `/` prefix. Accordingly using another prefix along with `addResourcePath` to me seemed to be the more official approach - that is why I have not dealt with the workaround presented [over there](https://community.rstudio.com/t/running-a-shiny-appobj-and-setting-a-resource-e-g-www-path/121697/2).

Answer (score 3):

It seems that this is [a bug in Shiny](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/3742).

Until this is fixed, there are two rough workaround strategies:

1. Convince Shiny that `www` should be mapped in a `shinyApp` object. To do this, we need to *modify* the `shinyApp` object:

   ```
   library(shiny)

   ui <- fluidPage(
     tags$img(src = 'photo.png')
   )

   server <- function(input, output) {}

   app <- shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
   app$staticPaths <- list(
     `/` = httpuv::staticPath(
       file.path(getwd(), "www"), indexhtml = FALSE, fallthrough = TRUE
     )
   )

   app
   ```

   <sub>(Solution based on a [RStudio Community discussion.](https://community.rstudio.com/t/running-a-shiny-appobj-and-setting-a-resource-e-g-www-path/121697/2))</sub>
2. Launch Shiny without using the `shinyApp` object directly:

   - by pressing the “Run App” button in RStudio, or
   - by executing `runApp('.')` or `runApp('app.R')`.

   Other ways of launching the app *do not work!* Notably, this also includes replacing the last line in the script with `runApp(shinyApp(ui, server))`.