# my shiny app does not load images after deploy on shinyapps.io but it works completely fine local

Tags: r, image, shiny, shinyapps

I had put all my images in "www" folder while deploying the app. But even though it is unable to load the image https://tejasviohlan.shinyapps.io/student/ while it works fine locally [you can look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S991E.png)

it is implemented `tags$img(src="filename.PNG")`

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53059211

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't capitalize the file extensions. Changing

```
tags$img(src="filename.PNG")
```

to

```
tags$img(src="filename.png")
```

will resolve the issue. Your operating system doesn't care, but the web protocol that serves the images does. As can be demonstrated by accessing one of the pictures from

> https://tejasviohlan.shinyapps.io/student/_w_5438387b/shiny.png

but not from

> https://tejasviohlan.shinyapps.io/student/_w_5438387b/shiny.PNG